# Trying to test my nested Rails 5 form (mintest)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, minitest, fields-for

The actual nested form itself works fine, but i'd like to be able to have a test covering it to make sure I don't screw it up later. I also have more nested forms planned so I'd really like to figure this out.

I'm getting this failing test in my ListControllerTest:

```
"ListItem.count" didn't change by 1.
 Expected: 1
 Actual: 0
```

With this code:

https://pastebin.com/BRdtZW2T

Note that the "List.count" bit does pass. Again, this does actually work exactly as it's supposed to. I can create lists with lists items no problem when I actually submit forms on my app.

Lists are created with form_for 
ListItems are created with fields_for

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. First off, I removed 'list_item_attributes' from the params being posted in my test. It seemed redundant, and I wasn't sure why I added it in there until I removed it, and my tests raised a different error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
    app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:15:in `[]'
```

No idea what this was about, but some google searches turned up this:

http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/29/rails-tricky-error-no-implicit-conversion-from-symbol-to-integer/

Which as it turns out is exactly my problem. So I added some extra square [] brackets to my params:[:list][:list_item], and presto it worked. See the revised pastebin as well as the article because that probably wasn't clear:

https://pastebin.com/uxRjsctK